# MySQL: GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to group by m.ID and have the SUM of (pm.amount_construction* prod.anzahl) for each m.id

Actually I have the following result:

```
Meterial_id | amount_construction | Anzahl_der_productionen | Total_amount
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
181         | 1                   | 10                      | 10
181         | 2                   | 20                      | 40
181         | 1                   | 100                     | 100
182         | 1                   | 10                      | 10
182         | 1                   | 20                      | 20
183         | 1                   | 100                     | 100
283         | 1                   | 5                       | 5
283         | 1                   | 10                      | 10
283         | 2                   | 100                     | 200
283         | 10                  | 55                      | 550
```

What I need is the following (column 2 and 3 are not necessary)

```
Meterial_id | Total_amount
---------------------------
181         | 150
182         | 30 
183         | 100
283         | 765
```

I tried `Group By m.id` and did `sum(pm.amount_construction * prod.anzahl)`
but I got strange results

Please see my code below:

```
SELECT
m.id As Meterial_id,    
pm.amount_construction AS amount_construction,    
prod.anzahl as Anzahl_der_productionen,    
(pm.amount_construction* prod.anzahl) as Total_amount

FROM produktion prod
JOIN projekt p    
   ON prod.projekt = p.id
JOIN kunden k    
   ON k.id = p.kunde
   LEFT JOIN bauteil b    
      ON b.produktion = prod.id    
JOIN product_material pm
JOIN material m    
   ON m.id = pm.material_id
JOIN product_configurationelement pce    
   ON pce.id = pm.product_configurationelement_id    
JOIN product_configurationelement_value pcev    
   ON pcev.product_configurationelement_id = pm.product_configurationelement_id    
   AND pcev.value_nr = pm.value_nr
JOIN product_type  pt
JOIN produkt pd
   ON pd.id = prod.produkt
JOIN product_generation pg
   ON pg.product_type_id = pt.id
JOIN product_modification pmm
   ON pmm.product_generation_id = pg.id
WHERE (prod.anzahl > 0 and pt.id = pd.product_type_id AND pm.product_generation_id = pd.product_generation_id  AND pg.generation = pd.generation AND p.starttermin <= '2018-07-05')    
ORDER BY m.id
```

Comment: Did you forget the GROUP BY?

Comment: On a sidenote: It seems strange that in your data model a product has exactly one product generation. I would rather expect there to be several generations for each product (so there should be no `produkt.product_generation_id`, but a `product_generation.product_id` instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many joins. Some of them are invalid. `JOIN` is short for `INNER JOIN` and needs an `ON` or `USING` clause. MySQL, however, silently converts the `JOIN` into a `CROSS JOIN` when you forget the clause. Then can lead to horrible mistakes, but you have hidden criteria in your `WHERE` clause, so all tables seem to be properly joined as far as I can see.

Anyway, many joins are not necessary. Why join with `bauteil` for example? There can be many `bauteil` per `produktion`, so you multiply the result by the number of bauteils. Same with `product_configurationelement`, `product_configurationelement_value`, `product_generation` and `product_modification` I guess. Then there are superfluous joins to `kunden`, `produkt` etc.

If I'm not mistaken this should be what you need: all `product_material` joined with `produktion` with the project matching a date range, grouped by `material_id` to get one result row per material.

```
SELECT
  pm.material_id,    
  SUM(pm.amount_construction * produktion.anzahl) as total_amount
FROM product_material pm
JOIN produkt p ON p.product_generation_id = pm.product_generation_id
JOIN produktion ON produktion.produkt = p.id and produktion.anzahl > 0
WHERE produktion.projekt IN (SELECT id FROM projekt WHERE starttermin <= date '2018-07-05')
GROUP BY pm.material_id
ORDER BY pm.material_id;
```

Comment: Thank you  Thorsten.. that did the job.. Thank  all of you for your help

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT
    m.id As Meterial_id,    
    sum(pm.amount_construction* prod.anzahl)

FROM 
    ....
GROUP BY m.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot the GROUP BY but that could be a typo and your query has other issues.  Any non-aggregated, non-grouped field in an aggregating query will have an effectively random value from the values encountered for that field under the grouped set of values. So, unless `pm` and `prod` are 1:1 with `m.id`, you will get unpredictable values that can change from one query execution to the next.

Most RDBMS do not even allow such a query, and MySql's latest default configurations disable the ability.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you will get your expected result

```
SELECT
m.id As Meterial_id,    
sum(pm.amount_construction* prod.anzahl) as Total_amount
FROM produktion prod
JOIN projekt p    
   ON prod.projekt = p.id
JOIN kunden k    
   ON k.id = p.kunde
   LEFT JOIN bauteil b    
      ON b.produktion = prod.id    
JOIN product_material pm
JOIN material m    
   ON m.id = pm.material_id
JOIN product_configurationelement pce    
   ON pce.id = pm.product_configurationelement_id    
JOIN product_configurationelement_value pcev    
   ON pcev.product_configurationelement_id = pm.product_configurationelement_id    
   AND pcev.value_nr = pm.value_nr
JOIN product_type  pt
JOIN produkt pd
   ON pd.id = prod.produkt
JOIN product_generation pg
   ON pg.product_type_id = pt.id
JOIN product_modification pmm
   ON pmm.product_generation_id = pg.id
WHERE (prod.anzahl > 0 and pt.id = pd.product_type_id AND pm.product_generation_id = pd.product_generation_id  AND pg.generation = pd.generation AND p.starttermin <= '2018-07-05')
group by m.id    
ORDER BY m.id
```